# Where to run tests to check

Tags: angularjs

I ran the test server (if I understand correctly) with help of karma. I have a browser window with the message "Karma v0.12.2 - connected". Next I have to run the tests form:

```
define([
    'app', 'jquery', 'angular',
    'angular', 'angularRoute', 'angularMocks'
],
function() {
    describe('UnitTest: App', function() {
        // just like normal
        it('is defined', function() {
            expect(_.size([1,2,3])).toEqual(3);
        });
    });
});
```

But I do not understand how to run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your command prompt or terminal depending on the OS you are using.

Navigate to the folder where your test folder and **karma.conf.js** lives. In your karma.conf.js make sure you specify the location of your test files.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        files: [
            // Test cases
            'Tests/unit/**/*spec.js'
        ]
```

On your terminal, type the command

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js
```

And you should see the result of the test on your terminal.

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket plwJXWX7daiEQHzUabTM
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 7): Executed 20 of 20 SUCCESS (2.565 secs / .891 secs)
```

Comment: and i have result:

    C:\test>karma start karma.conf.js
    INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.2 server started at http://localhost:64/
    INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
    INFO [Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket sXjyKe-5uYMmAqpHf07U wi
    th id 3918212
    Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 8): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.007 secs / 0 secs)

But Executed 0 of 0. Where from this "executes" and how this work on some application?

Comment: If feel you are missing the concept of unit testing. You need to have two files say app.js and then app.spec.js. The purpose of app.spec.js is to test app.js by using the functions you created on app.js. For example, app.js has function sum (a,b) { return a + b } on your app.spec.js you would have an expectation of what the result would be it('should return the sum of two number', function(){ expect(sum(1+2)).toEqual(3)});

Comment: Yes, the book does not have a precise details and examples, there is more on the calculation of knowledgeable users, sometimes lacking one or more chains in the sample.
I'll try to adjust.

Comment: Okay, if app.spec.js in 'Tests/unit/**/*spec.js', where be app.js?
And be sure whether a match file names for app.spec.js app.js, or you can call to say test1.js app.js. And as this file understands that he must serve app.js?
And many thanks for the previous answers )

Oh, i have error: Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 8) ERROR Uncaught ReferenceError: it is not defined
 at C:/lesson16/test/app.spec.js:1